# Connection with mySQL from JAVA in Linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux

I have a problem with the connection to mySQL from Java. I am using Linux with NetBeans, and I downloaded the specific driver. I have mySQL in xampp.

My code is:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombreBaseDatos",
           "user",
           "pass"
     );
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(BD1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(BD1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

And the error I get is this:

> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>   due to underlying exception:
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.net.ConnectException MESSAGE: Conexión rehusada
>
> STACKTRACE:
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425) at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:271) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215) at
>   bd.pkg1.BD1.main(BD1.java:25)
>
> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago. at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)

Can somebody help me make this connection?

Answer (score 0):

This would suggest to me that MySql is not accepting connections at localhost:3306

Is this the case ? Does a simple

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

connect to a receiving port on your machine ? Do you need to [configure MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-networking.html) for such connections ?

Comment: I tried the same code with another connections strings like "jdbc:mysql://localhost/nombreBaseDatos" and the error was the same

Comment: As suggested by Brian: Your MySQL server does not accept connections on the given port. Maybe it is not started or a firewall is in place that prevents you from connecting.